# Dot and Dense questions in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

code:

```
a=Input(shape=(6,10,64))
b=Input(shape=(6,64,1))
c=Dot(axes=[-1,2])([a,b])
c=Dense(10)(c)
```

But the Dot layer did not report an error,The Dense layer gave us the wrong report.the error is Dimensions must be equal.How to solve this problem .Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you want `dot product` here?

Comment: This is not my original code. My code doesn't have to dot two inputs to begin with, but it does have to do one step and then I have this problem

Comment: It would help if you paste the completed code or minimal example code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've solved my problem by using a low-level API called batch_dot
This Dot layer seems to work only on the first None dimension and not on the next six dimensions.